# Generating Update and cancel buttons on clicking edit button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've a content page that dynamically binds a grid view. I've added the edit and delete buttons also. But on clicking edit button, how to generate the update and cancel link buttons.

I know that it must be handled in RowEditing Event. Please help me in detail how to get those buttons.
 Here is the ap.net webpage

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ManageSMS.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm10.aspx.cs" Inherits="SMS_Mod2.WebForm10" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Visible="false" runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></asp:Panel>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton ="true" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the Code behind file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BOL;
using DAL;
namespace SMS_Mod2
{
    public partial class WebForm10 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        StationaryManagement stMgmt = new StationaryManagement();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "0"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Branch", "1"));
                //DropDownList1.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                Panel1.Visible = true;
                DropDownList2.DataSource = stMgmt.ViewBranches();
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "BranchName";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "BranchID";
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please select", "0"));
            }
            else
            {
                Panel1.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                GridView1.DataSource = stMgmt.ViewLocations(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
            GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
            GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a `AutoGenerateEditButton` property you could use instead. This setting will also show update/cancel buttons when editing.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
    <Columns>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

To update your grid you will also need to use following GridView events: `OnRowEditing`, `OnRowCancelingEdit` and `OnRowUpdating`.

In the edit event you usually don't need to do anything. In the update event in your code-behind you will need to do your update logic and finally set `GridView1.EditIndex = -1;` to end editing. And finally in the cancel event you just need to set EditIndex to -1 again.

There is also a property to autogenerate delete buttons. Then you need to remove the row from your dataset in `OnRowDeleting` event if I recall correctly.

The GridView will look something like this then:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
```